# Most popular nested category

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem I am trying to solve in python. I have one dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame{'company':[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],'category':['a','a','a','c','a','b','b','b','a']}
```

[image]

And I would like to know, by company what is the most popular category, the output being:

[image]

For company 2, it could either category a or b, not both, it could be chosen at random.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `groupby()` and `mode`:

```
df.groupby('company', as_index=False)['category'].apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
```

Output:

```
   company category
0        1        a
1        2        a
2        3        b
```